# Magento Upgrade to 1.9 - Shopping Cart Broken

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.9

I have upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9 and now the shopping cart is broken.

No items can be added at all.

Whats happened?

I have Googled for the issue but come up with nothing so far.

Comment: It might be an issue with form keys, introduced in Magento 1.8.

Comment: If you don't use any fullpage cache like varnish, and form_keys are not the reason, check out my question, how i debugged it and what the reason was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525430/magento-upgrade-1-7-1-9-db-issue/26528326#26528326